# Fabric.js change image background color

Tags: asp.net, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have one png image as background on my canvas. Now I'm trying to change it color but all the examples that i found need index value. 
Is it possible to change background images, already uploaded, colors?

this is the filter that I'm trying to apply:

```
       function applyFilterWithColor(color, objectIndex) {

            var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
                color: color,
                mode: 'multiply'
            });

            var obj = canvas.getItem("Base");
            obj.filters.push(filter);
            obj.applyFilters();
            canvas.renderAll();

        };
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'index value'? The function you posted doesn't use `objectIndex` anywhere, so I'm not sure what it's supposed to be used for. Also, none of fabric.js classes have `.getItem()` method - are you sure you're giving all necessary info in the question?

Comment: shkaper, my mistake I have modified this function. But the main question is: How can I change background image color? I'm a noob with Fabric.js.

Comment: Is this background image an instance of `fabric.Image`? How was it created?

Comment: It was created. I've resolved the problem (I think is not the best way) doing the set of background image when I need to change it color...